# JPA entity persistent field not fetched when listing

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

I am building a JSF CRUD web application using JPA. I want to list all entities of typ `Supplier` I can fetch from the db. But one of the fields (`articleList`) in `Supplier` are not neccessary when creating a list view and will consume alot of time if it is fetched when listing all content of `Supplier`. Is there a way to supress this in this instance, but have that field information fetched when looking at the detail information of `Supplier`.

This is `Supplier`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "supplier")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Supplier.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Supplier s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Supplier.findBySid", query = "SELECT s FROM Supplier s WHERE s.sid = :sid")})
public class Supplier implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "SID")
    private Short sid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Supplier")
    private String supplier;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "supplierSID")
    private List<Article> articleList;
```

I don't wan't `articleList` to be filled in from the database when performing the findAll query. Can I control this somehow?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#fetch%28%29) `@OneToMany` should already have fetch type LAZY, so either you're overriding that somewhere or access the list. Any chance you're calling `articleList.size()` somewhere?

Comment: No, I wasn't doing that. I didn't know about lazy fetching and that the `@OneToMany` would default to this. It was more an assumtion that it would/might become a problem.

Comment: *The default fetch type is LAZY for all relationships except for OneToOne and ManyToOne,*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Lazy Fetching](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Lazy_Fetching) with `fetch` attribute setted to [`FetchType.LAZY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html)

> Lazy fetching allows the fetching of a relationship to be deferred until it is accessed. This is important not only to avoid the database access, but also to avoid the cost of building the objects if they are not needed.

Sample usage

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "supplierSID")
private List<Article> articleList;
```

> **`fetch`** -  Defines strategies for fetching data from the database. (...) The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime that data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LAZY property for not fetchig this elements view mode.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "supplierSID")
private List<Article> articleList;
```

For details need to write one method which preload this LAZY attribute. For example:

```
public Supplier getFullSuplierEntity(Supplier supplier) {
   supplier.getArticleList().size();   
   return supplier;
}
```

In this case JPA run more sql SELECT for fetch articleList.